# Reading the mtvec register on RISC-V

Tags: riscv

How to read the content of the mtvec register?

Answer (score 0):

mtvec is a CSR system register.

To read: It can be read by the csrrw instruction into an integer register as first and third parameter (should be the same). The second parameter is the mtvec system register index. As a shortcut csrr can be used.

E.g.
`csrrw t0, mtvec, t0`
to read mtvec into t0.

To write: It can also be copied from an integer register with the csrrw instruction. The first parameter specifies another integer register, which will hold the previous value afterwards.

E.g.
`csrrw t0, mtvec, t1`
to read old mtvec into t0 and write t1 into mtvec as new value.

Comment: can u please elaborate more? how to use csrrw instruction?